# The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8090/'

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, wcfserviceclient

I have gone through many answers on Stackoverflow before posting my question. None of the answers seemed to resolve my issue. I have created a simple WCF service and have hosted it in Console application using TCP binding.

My Host App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                       protectionLevel="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexbehavior" name="EmailService.PAEmail">
        <endpoint address="MailService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="EmailService.IPAEmail" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>      
        <behavior name="mexbehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My contracts:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IPAEmail
    {
        [OperationContract]         
        void SendMail();
    }

 public class PAEmail : IPAEmail
    {
       public void SendMail()
        {
           
        }
    }
```

My host:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost obj = new ServiceHost(typeof(EmailService.PAEmail)))
            {
                obj.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The host is running in my pc.
From my client, if i try to add service reference, it gives me this error:

The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8090/'.
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8090/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:04.0092984. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8090.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8090
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you used **using** and released the servicehost after creating the servicehost.You can put **Console.ReadLine()** in **using** so that ServiceHost is not released immediately:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost obj = new ServiceHost(typeof(PAEmail)))
            {
                obj.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
        }
```

You can also choose not to use **using**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ServiceHost obj = new ServiceHost(typeof(PAEmail));
                obj.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                obj.Close();
            }
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks a lot.! That was a terrible mistake from my end.